# How to solve in this NullPointerException with android code?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-custom-view

This is the function in DragFrame.class code :

```
public void setFragment(FragmentManager fm, Fragment fragment) {
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_drag, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

DragFrame.class is a custom view using for enabling drag frame. And I added this custom view in my activity_main.xml :

```
<com.android.example.exercise.Drag.DragFrame
    android:id="@+id/drag_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

In my MainActivity.class, I put this code :

```
dragFrame = (DragFrame) findViewById(R.id.drag_frame);

dragFrame.setFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), new DragFragment());
dragFrame.setOnDragListener(this);
dragFrame.close();
```

But the error occurred, and error contents are like that :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.android.example.exercise.Drag.DragFrame.setFragment(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager, androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)' on a null object reference
    at com.android.example.exercise.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
```

Line 78 is the `dragFrame.setFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), new DragFragment);`. What is the problem in my code?? I tried to put the code in MainActivity.class :

```
if (dragFrame != null && getSupportFragmentManager() != null) {
        dragFrame.setFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), new DragFragment());
        dragFrame.setOnDragListener(this);
        dragFrame.close();
    }
```

But it doesn't work; How can I fix this code??

Comment: What happen in my eyes and hands?? I'm sorry; I edited

Answer (score 4):

the `dragFrame` is the one null and you are testing on `playFragment` reread the error

```
com.android.example.exercise.Drag.**DragFrame**.setFragment(FragmentManager, Fragment)' on a null object reference
```

Do this :

```
if (dragFrame != null && getSupportFragmentManager() != null) {
        dragFrame.setFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), new DragFragment());
        dragFrame.setOnDragListener(this);
        dragFrame.close();
    }
```

Comment: Great observation!

Comment: dragFrame is null but you are testing on dragFragment,